# Why does CKKS decryption have approximate correctness?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm looking at the following text:

[image]

Why does CKKS decryption have an approximate correctness requiring that $\|u + e\| < {q / 2}$?

I mean if $\|u + e\| \ge {q / 2}$, how can I prove the CKKS decryption doesn't have approximate correctness?

Answer (score 2):

All of lattice-based cryptography has similar restrictions to this.
The easiest way to understand it is that lattice-based cryptography is implicitly made up of two parts

- the *encryption* part, for example (in secret-key encryption, i.e. the simplest setting) $\mathsf{Enc}_s(m) = (A, As + e + m)$
- the *error-correction* part, in that same secret key setting we encrypt $(q/2)m$ rather than $m$.

In this simplified example, we include this error-correction because we cannot decrypt standard encryption.
In particular

$$\mathsf{Dec}_s(\mathsf{Enc}_s(m)) = \mathsf{Dec}_s(A, b:= As +m+ e) = b - As = m + e\neq m.$$

We can't decrypt *precisely* because of the presence of the error $e$.
So we need a method of removing this error.
In particular, encoding $m\mapsto (q/2)m$ lets us decode $c :=(q/2)m+e$ by rounding $c\mapsto \lfloor c/(q/2)\rceil$.
This is equivalent to treating $c$ as an expression *over $\mathbb{Z}$* (**not** $\mathbb{Z}_q$), and using standard techniques from coding theory (namely solving CVP on the lattice $(q/2)\mathbb{Z}^m$).

For CKKS, it can be viewed as *essentially* the same construction, except

- you do FHE things (this doesn't change things much for the purposes of this question)
- The encoding $m\mapsto (q/2)m$ (or more generally $m\mapsto (q/2^k)m$) isn't injective, but is instead "lossy".

By this, I mean that there are multiple $m, m'$ that will be encoded to the same value under the error-correction step.
This means that the final result (after error-correction) may be "wrong", but it is wrong in a particular way.
Namely, it is *right*, but for a computation done on a *wrong* (lower-precision) value.
I'm pretty sure this is related to the notion of [backwards numerical stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability#Stability_in_numerical_linear_algebra), but I'm not really an expert in that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/77478956

In summary, it keeps the same odd/even feature of the result, resulting in the wrong answer/message.

Comment: given that this is an english-language site, it might be useful to mention that this link is in chinese.